# Tool to test analog phone line connection quality

Tags: analog, telephone

An ancillary job of mine is to support an analog phone line for our credit card machine. From time to time AT&T changes out hardware in the core which causes the machine's modem to not connect over the phone line.

Testing the line by plugging in an anlog phone is not rigorous enough. Often the phone will have a dial tone and place calls, but there is too much noise for the modem.

I am looking for a hardware tool I can plug into the RJ-11 jack which will evaluate the line quality. I have a budget of up to a couple hundred dollars if necessary. I need to know if the line quality is degraded and unable to carry a modem connection.

I appreciate any recommendations of a tool to do this job.

Comment: Line quality is probably most influenced by balance relative to ground.

Faults which produce leakage wrt ground in one leg more than the other will result in received noise due to induced mains being converted from common more to differential. Measuring balance wrt ground is the main aim but measurement of the amount of differential mains hum is probably a good indicator.

Comment: Do you want to know how to construct a circuit to analyze an analog phone line for connection quality, or what tools to buy?  It seems like the former (which would be a good thing, the latter isn't a good question for this site), given that you've linked to the Fluke website but wanted more.

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic and will be closed. No design is involved.

Comment: Do all questions in this community need to be how to design something?  Why would I design a tool which is mass produced cheaply already?  I just need some information to help me select the right tool.  Sure I'd be interested to know how it works, but I see no need to build one.

Comment: Read the Faq. NO shopping questions!

Comment: If you limit the community to design topics only then I think you are excluding enthusiasts who work in related fields.  But maybe that's what you want.

Comment: This community is intended for people with design problems, not people who just want to buy something.

Comment: @steampowered, if you are wanting to find what techniques exist for measuring this type of thing, I think we can go with answering for what kind of tools will help with this. That works great. If you are wanting a link to a part to buy it is too localized for our site. I hope this distinction is clear, if it is not feel free to contact me in chat.

Comment: By signing up for this site and formulating a question on how to do something myself which is normally done by a technician, I am demonstrating a desire to learn.  I could easily pay a contractor to do this, but I chose the route which requires me to learn and get involved with how the technology works.

Comment: Generally speaking, almost all POTs providers have the ability to check signal quality. Just call them up and tell them what you have going on and ask them to check signal quality. This will be cheaper then buying anything yourself.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Meta fully supports the ability to link to any questions to provide context. Just posting comments creates a bunch of unconnected, unsearchable complaining. And I am not sure why you call it "my" policy. I am just as much a user for this site as you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a line to transmit a digital signal somewhere and then this device would call this number. Off the shelf modems would probably be ok since you just need it at one place. Your device could just be a circuit that generates the same signal and computes the correlation with the signal.